# Why does Python print the else statement here?

Tags: python, if-statement

The output of the below code is

```
Hello
Hola
```

Why does it print the "Hola"? Shouldn't the else statement be exempt when passing 'en' into the function?

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == 'en':
        print("Hello")
    if lang == 'fr':
        print('Bonjour')
    else:
        print('Hola')

greet('en')
```

Comment: You have 2 separate if statements. Replace the second if with `elif` (else-if) to make it only work if the first condition does not hold.

Comment: Ah, I understand. The second if needs to be an elif. Goddit.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `elif` instead.

```
def greet(lang):
    if lang == 'en':
        print("Hello")
    elif lang == 'fr':
        print('Bonjour')
    else:
        print('Hola')

greet('en')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because  it runs the first statement of if  but you haven't used  '{}' here and condition is true

i.e lang =='en'

so it prints `hello` then first if statements doesn't have else statement so
it goes to next if which is false because lang is not `fr` so it printing else statement also..

overall you are checking two conditions first will print `Hello` and next will print else statement which is `Hola`

to print only Hello you should use nested if-else statement here